# Cloud9 IDE does not display Google Fonts

Tags: html, css, cloud9-ide, google-font-api

I'm trying to use Google Fonts on Cloud9 IDE, but the page keeps displaying the default font.

At first I thought there's something wrong with my code, but I've stripped down the HTML and CSS to a minimum, and it still does not work.

I've tried the same code on codepen.io, there it works just fine.

Is there a known issue with Google Fonts on Cloud9, or there's something that I'm missing?

Here are the links to [Workspace in Cloud9](https://ide.c9.io/srlle/google_fonts_problem) and [Pen in Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pBwaF).

And here's the code that I'm using.

**HTML:**

```
<head>

      <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
        <h1>This is a text.</h1>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
h1 {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are loading the font from an HTTP resource while Cloud9's preview is loading the html page over HTTPS. Try changing the protocol of the font url to https. You could've found the error message in the browser's console: http://screencast.com/t/2vIF2y2rLZt

Comment: Brilliant, it works! Thanks Ruben! Bonus thanks for pointing me to browser's console. :)

Comment: Man I've spent hours on this... Wish I found this sooner. Thanks man